# SendGrid Apex attachment functionality only works for text files?

Tags: salesforce, apex, sendgrid

I am using Send Grid Apex package for sending out bulk email from salesforce. It's possible to send text files as an attachment with the help of Send Grid API, but it fails for every other type of files (like PDF etc).

Is there any workaround for this problem? I have tried calling web API of sendgrid for attachments from Apex code with the help of callouts. Its not working for PDF and other files.

API doc:
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-apex

Comment: I assume you are using [addAttachmentStream](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-apex#addattachmentstream). In what way is if failing for non-text attachments? Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: Yes , I am using addAttachmentStream API but not getting any errors while sending . But when i try to open the pdf doc at receiving end PDF reader shows that the document is invalid.

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-apex/blob/1b0f8da106d94a17c6ff0e61b52368abd9d0f02d/src/classes/SendGrid.cls#L209), it appears the blob data gets URL encoded and posted in the body of the `HtmlRequest` to sendgrid. Maybe check how SendGrid is expecting to receive a PDF attachment. The encoding on this seems unlikely to work.

Comment: Exactly. Just trying out few pdf's. In some cases , i get 
**BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string**  error. I have checked the similar library implemented in JAVA. It works for every attachment. Not sure how to implement this in APEX.

Comment: How does SendGrid expect blob information to be encoded as a string. Base 65 is a common way of dealing with binary data

Comment: Whoops, meant Base64 encoding of binary/blob data.

Comment: By looking at the sendgrid-apex package sendgrid is treating everything as UTF-8 which is totally wrong. I am going to try out the web API instead of apex integration. But i have seen many posts which says that its problematic to send multipart blob data to external webservice. Anyways will try it out.